# Use mongoose in an angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I try to integrate MongoDB in my project angular 6. I want to use the ODM Mongoose.

*npm install mongoose --save*

I created this service which must manage the connection with the database

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { mongoose } from 'mongoose';
@Injectable()
export class BD {

    private bd;
    public test: string; 

    constructor(mongoose: mongoose){}
    Test(){
        mongoose('the url of the database')
        this.bd = mongoose.connection;
        this.bd.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'error: impossible connection to the database'));
        this.bd.once('open', ()=>{console.log('connected to the DB :}')})
    }
}
```

When I launch the application in my browser I have this erreur:

*SCRIPT5009: 'global' is not defined*

What does this error mean?
Is this how I have to import mongoose?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: the module `mongoose` which you're using isn't for frontend, you cannot use it for angular frontend. Since the error said that there is no variable `global`, because it only exists in Node.JS, not browser. p/s: I think your implementation isn't correct because you're trying to create a connection from EVERY connection to your app.  What if you have reached 1000 users and they would create 1000 connections.

Comment: It was for a test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoose is a library designed specially for node.js and won't work in the browser environment. In order to be able to connect the db - you need to establish node.js back-end server, for example [express.js](http://expressjs.com/). Then you will be able access your resources through the REST api.

Also, you cannot establish connection to the database directly, because you need somehow secure the data inside those database. When you connecting to the database directly - everyone who can take a look at your code will gain acess to the data and this is serious security problem.